# Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:library:3.1.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After updating android studio 3.1.2 my existing project gives error at

```
dataBinding.enabled = true
```

error is as follows-

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:library:3.1.2
Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:adapters:3.1.2
```

my gradle dependency are as follows-

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3'

implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.0'

// Instrumentation dependencies use androidTestCompile
// (as opposed to testCompile for local unit tests run in the JVM)
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
```

}

I also tried

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

but its also not working

When I tried to update build tool version to 4.4 then I found this error. I f I do not update the build tool version then its working fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

check it this below code in your project level gradle file ..

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they    belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Adding google() inside allprojects's repositories tag worked for me. I guess it could not downloaded the binding library because its a part of  google maven repository.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Android Team](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50042923/1856562) answer you had to add

> google() 
>   too all repositories

and priority is important. so other repositories must be added after google()

Comment: His answer is right. buildscript > repositories and allprojects > repositories both need `google()`.

Comment: My gradle script had google() as the last entry.  Moved it to the first and sync became successful.  What is life?

Answer (score 3):

Downgrade to 3.1.0 in project level build.gradle file, then rebuild the project.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: probably there is a typo. You said you downgraded from 3.1.0 to 3.1.0 :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also has the same issue I ensured that I added google() to all repositories and also I downgraded gradle to 3.1.0 from 3.1.4 and my project was successfully build.

Another TIP: We can also add the below code to our build.gradle(project) which takes cares of libraries conflicts with new dependencies

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force"com.android.support:supportannotations:$androidSupportVersion"
        force "com.android.support:support-v4:$androidSupportVersion"
        force "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$androidSupportVersion"
        force "com.android.support:design:$androidSupportVersion"
        force "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$androidSupportVersion"
    }
}
```

And you can keep your libraries in a separate file such as libraries.gradle and include them in build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript
    {
    apply from: "./libraries.gradle"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added **`Data-Binding`** to my project and the next time I build project, I faced the same issue, more specifically logcat displayed this message:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:library:3.1.2
>
> Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:adapters:3.1.2

As per accepted answer, I checked my **Project Level Gradle File** to see whether it was missing `google()` in its repositories, but it was already there.

Build multiple times, but all in vain.

Then I did what my Android Master once told me to do, just in case when everything fails.

**File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart**.

Next time the project opened it build successfully.